# No line found Exception in java with Scanner

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I want to read in lines from a *.txt* file. However while the file is found, I can't access its content.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    File myObj = new File("C:\\Daten\\workspaces\\my_file.txt");
    System.out.println(myObj);
    Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
    System.out.println("test1");
    
    System.out.println(myObj.getName());
            
    String insertInto = "INSERT INTO ";
    insertInto = insertInto.concat(myObj.getName() +" ( ");
                        
    //get header
    System.out.println("hast next ?");
    System.out.println(myReader.hasNextLine());
    String header = myReader.nextLine();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

and this causes the following output:

```
C:\Daten\workspaces\my_file.txt
test1
my_file.txt
hast next ?
false

... threw exception
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
...
```

The file is a tab limited text file and I rechecked the path multiple times: it is at this location and is not empty.

At this point I really don't know anymore what the problem is and I feel like I'm searching in the wrong place, but I don't know where I'm supposed to search.

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: `hast next ?
false`

Comment: why don't you use this Constructor? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File)

Comment: @ScaryWombat I did, same result, i actually startet with that one before i tried the absolut path one.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: Please try `System.out.println(myObj.exists());`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Somehow the file was corrupted or so. I tried a new different dummy file and it could read the lines. So I then i simply copied the content of the my_file.txt into a new .txt and it worked.
I still have no idea why though.

PS: Thanks for your help Wombat.